# process a string of ascii Hex values into a numerical hex value

Tags: python-2.7

I'm still fairly new at python so forgive me if this is a fairly easy question, but I didn't find anything obvious through searching.

I've got a string of Ascii hex in the form of:

```
7F 9D AA 3E F7 0E 9C 75 7C 37
```

What I'm trying to do is extract a number from the table (for example 7F) and then convert it into a hex value that I can then perform a mathematical operation on.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Which step are you stuck on? Can you extract the individual "words" from the string? Can you convert the "words" to numbers?

Comment: Both parts really, but I could probably work out the extracting the "words" from the string.

Comment: Well why don't you try that, have a look at [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) and return if you get stuck. You really should try something before asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply need to convert a string representation of a hex value to an non-string version, you can use binascii to convert your string representation to its hex equivalent:

```
import binascii
h = "7F 9D AA 3E F7 0E 9C 75 7C 37"
binascii.unhexlify(''.join(h.split()))

# >> '\x7f\x9d\xaa>\xf7\x0e\x9cu|7'
```

If you need integers, convert your string into a list (so that you are able to iterate over it) and then use `int()` to convert your base-16 hexadecimal numbers back to integers:

```
hex_list = "7F 9D AA 3E F7 0E 9C 75 7C 37"

# Convert your string list to a list: e.g. ['7F', '9D', 'AA'...
hex_list = hex_list.split()

for hex in hex_list: 
    print int(hex, 16) #hex is base 16
```

To convert just a single list value, specify its index in your list:

```
# Convert 7F back to an integer:
print int(hex_list[0], 16)
```

To convert an int back to hex, simply pass into `hex()`.